# Apply raw string to function return value

Tags: python

I'm not sure if I've phrased it correctly, but hopefully the example will clear it up:

```
re.search(fileMask.replace('*','.*?'),fileName):
```

For the first parameter in the re.search() call, how can I ensure that I will pass the value returned by the fileMask.replace() call as a raw string?

Something to the effect of:

```
re.search(r'fileMask.replace('*','.*?')',fileName):
```

..although that won't work because I actually need the fileMask function to be called.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but just wondering whether the glob module might help http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#module-glob

Answer (score 2):

There is no such type as "a raw string" -- there are *literals* (of string types) that are so named, but the objects such literals stand for are string objects -- nothing more, nothing less.  For example, literals `r'a\b''` (a "raw string literal") and `'a\\b'` (a normal string literal) represent exactly the **same** string value: one of length three, with characters a, backlash, and b, in this order.  If you print these objects, both display as `a\b`; if you print their `repr`, it's `a\\b` in both cases.

So, it's hard to understand your question.  Could you give examples of some possible values for `fileMask` and `fileName`, and the results you expect from the consequent `re.search` calls?

Also,

> I actually need the fileMask function
>   to be called.

That might really be a problem, because there appears to be no **function** named `fileMask`, but rather (it would seem) a **string** thus named.  Do you mean "need the method of fileMask to be called"?

Comment: I meant that I need the replace method called of the string variable fileMask. To put my question another way:
myFunctionA(myFunctionB()) - 

Without modifying myFunctionB(), how can I ensure the return value of myFunctionB is passed as a "raw string" to myFunctionA in the above statement?

Comment: @rmisio, there **is** no such thing as `passed as a "raw string"`: reread my answer.  A raw string LITERAL (there is no other kind of "raw string"!) is just a slightly different SYNTAX to express a perfectly normal string at compile time; there just is no such thing as "passing as" (at runtime) any specific alternative form of compile-time *syntax* -- seriously, your repeated assertion to the contrary makes as much sense as the famous "colorless green ideas sleep furiously".  **PLEASE** edit your Q to provide **examples**, as I already asked you to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.search(fileMask.replace('\*','\.\*?').encode('string_escape'), fileName):
```

Comment: As long as r'some text' is equivilant to 'some text'.encode('string_escape'), then this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: It is.  `'\r\n' == r'\r\n'` returns False, and `'\r\n'.encode('string_escape') == r'\r\n'` returns True.

Comment: This doesn't work for all strings and all escapes, alas: '\232'.encode('string_escape') == '\\x9a'